# Android Screenshot with Virtual Keyboard (Programatically)

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard, screenshot

I got a project which includes **screenshot of android content's root view**. But if someone click a **edittext** and open virtual keyboard i can't get this keyboard view in my picture.I mean android content's root view doesn't contain virtual keyboard. How can i add it ?
Here is my screenshot code :

```
Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    OutputStream fout = null;
    imageFile = new File(filePath);
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And also i'm working on android emulator. Thanks for your replies from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this, as you can only get the contents of the Views within your own app. On Android, the keyboard counts as a third party app, and you cannot get its view content.

If you have access to an Android 4.0 or above (or some other devices running lower versions but with screenshot capabilities added by the manufacturer (like some of the Samsung Galaxy Series devices)), you can take a screenshot of the whole screen by pressing the power button and the volume down button (key combinations may differ on non Nexus devices).

Other than that, you could try parsing the framebuffer, which requires root access on some devices. The framebuffer is usually located at `/dev/fb0` or `/dev/graphics/fb0`. On some devices (like an LG Optimus One) this can be accessed without root privileges, but on the majority (like a Nexus S) of them you need to be rooted for this. This is usually not allowed for security reasons, as a malicious app could take screenshots in the background and send them to a remote server, revealing information like email IDs and passwords, and in some cases bank account details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know teamviewer application ? I'm working on a project such as TeamViewer and i have to do it.I've just done project on Java but as we all know andorid is really different. Also android got teamviewer. I wonder how it works if it can control android keyboard. If it's possible with "framebuffer" think could you explain more about it ?

Comment: What do you mean by `control android keyboard`?

Comment: From a remote server i have to control and press keyboard.

Comment: You can add text to views within your own app, but not outside of your app.

Comment: Looks like you never used Teamviewer application. I dont want to add text. From TCP Server ; for example ; i'm sending "press A" command and android application is doing in it's own. But for doing this i need keyboard picture. I think i'm gonna draw it with another command. Thanks for your reply anyway.